Use Kubernetes service-account for calling Vertex AI
We have a Kubernetes cluster where one of the containers runs a FastAPI app.
The FastAPI app have a route /predict/ which should call an endpoint in VertexAi where a Transformer model is deployed, which encodes the incomming data and returns a list of floats.
The function for making the call is
import json
import os
from typing import Final, List

from google.oauth2 import service_account
from langchain_community.embeddings import AzureOpenAIEmbeddings

from google.cloud import aiplatform_v1


__API_KEY: Final = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(json.loads(_get_api_key()))

async def get_vertex_embeddings(data: str) -> List[float]:
    region = os.environ["VertexAi__Region"]
    client = aiplatform_v1.PredictionServiceAsyncClient(
        client_options={"api_endpoint": f"{region}-aiplatform.googleapis.com"},
        credentials=__API_KEY
    )

    project_id = os.environ["VertexAi__ProjectId"
    endpoint_id = os.environ["VertexAi__EndpointId"]

    endpoint = client.endpoint_path(project=project_id, location=region, endpoint=endpoint_id)

    instance = {"data": data}
    instances = [instance]
    try:
        response = await client.predict(endpoint=endpoint, instances=instances)
        return response.predictions
    except Exception as e:
        print("DEBUG - failed internal with", str(e))


it works great manually but in production we would like to avoid the __API_KEY part and just use the service-account which runs the container.
I have tried just uncomment the credentials arg i.e
    client = aiplatform_v1.PredictionServiceAsyncClient(
        client_options={"api_endpoint": f"{region}-aiplatform.googleapis.com"}
    )

but that does not seem to work. The container simply crashes completely when getting to response = await client.predict(endpoint=endpoint, instances=instances) (not even the try/catch catches the error thus it is really difficult to figure out what is the issue).
Locally it works fine, but I'm logged into google locally thus I assume it just uses my local-credentials.
The question is, how do I use the service-account which runs the container in production thus skipping the "credentials" part?
NOTE: It turns out that using the sync client instead of async works. No idea why

Hi @CutePoison, Could you check this documentation for custom service account ? Let me know if this helps you or not.

The best way to do this is to use Workload Identity Federation for GKE. Using this mechanism, you associate Kubernetes service accounts with Google Cloud (IAM) Service Accounts such that Application Default Credentials works for GKE workloads too. The process is a little tedious but, if you follow the instructions, the solution works flawlessly and is a powerful, secure solution.

Hi @CutePoison, I have posted a community answer as per the comments for the sake of community who might encounter this issue in future, do consider accepting and upvoting it as per Stack Overflow guidelines, helping more Stack contributors with their research. Please feel free to edit the answer for any additional information

As Commented by @DazWikin, The best way to do this is to use Workload Identity Federation for GKE. Using this mechanism, you associate Kubernetes service accounts with Google Cloud (IAM) Service Accounts such that Application Default Credentials works for GKE workloads too. The process is a little tedious but, if you follow the instructions, the solution works flawlessly and is a powerful, secure solution.
Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future. Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.
